# Block.io NodeJS module has no method get_notifications?

Tags: javascript, node.js

coin_client.js has the following code:

```
var BlockIo = require('block_io');
var version = 2;
var API_Key = myAPIkey;
var PIN = "mypincode";
var block_io = new BlockIo(API_Key, PIN, version);


exports.getBalance = function(callback){
    block_io.get_balance({}, function(err,data){
        console.log(err);    
    });
}

exports.listNotifications = function(callback){
    block_io.get_notifications({}, function(err,data){
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

And the main module contains the following:

```
var coin_client = require("coin_client");

coin_client.getBalance();
coin_client.listNotifications();
```

When I'm trying to execute main module, the first function - getBalance() - works perfectly, it stops on listNotifications() with the following error:

```
    block_io.get_notifications({}, function(err,data){
             ^
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'get_notifications'
    at Object.exports.listNotifications
```

There's the developer's doc: 
https://block.io/docs/notifications/nodejs

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is coin_client.js. I suspect some nodejs module.

BlockIo does provide such method since

https://github.com/BlockIo/block_io-nodejs/commit/83fdc27cccd1b36ca605d6ab87371d58ccfdc6e4

which is included in latest release 1.0.9

https://github.com/BlockIo/block_io-nodejs/releases/tag/1.0.9

So, maybe you need to check the package file of your coin client and verify that version matches. Maybe you need to run `npm update`.

Comment: You will be laugh, but... Yes... =)) I've tried a lot of ways, but the simpliest was the right one. I thought I'm going crazy =))) Thank you!